# How does $\cos^{-1} (1/\sqrt2) = \pi/4$ ? I thought $\cos(\pi/4) = \sqrt2/2$

Tags: trigonometry

> How does $\cos^{-1} (1/\sqrt2) = \pi/4$ ? I thought $\cos(\pi/4) = \sqrt2/2$

I am awful at formatting, thank you ahead of time.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: The body of questions is not meant to thank users. The title is also formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Both equations are true:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=\frac{\sqrt2}{(\sqrt2)^2}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Did not realize this.